# Service not starting at reboot

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-broadcast

I'm trying start a service at the time of booting the device. I have searched many all over and followed the steps and it is still not working out. Once the mobile reboots it shows in the beginning that "application has stopped unexpectedly". I know it is from the receiver file, but couldn't figure out where particularly the problem is.

Receiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.setAction("com.androidhive.jsonparsing.UpdateService");
            context.startService(myIntent);
        }
    }   
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AndroidJSONParsingActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Single List Item View -->
    <activity
        android:label="Single Menu Item"
        android:name=".SingleMenuItemActivity" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".UpdateService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.androidhive.jsonparsing.UpdateService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Is there anything I need to add so that the service starts perfectly.

Comment: what is shown in the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Please check you android manifest it should be like this :

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".AndroidJSONParsingActivity" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<!-- Single List Item View -->
<activity
    android:label="Single Menu Item"
    android:name=".SingleMenuItemActivity" >
</activity>
<service android:name=".UpdateService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.androidhive.jsonparsing.UpdateService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver android:name=".Receiver" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The problem is in declaration of your receiver.
Please check the android:name tag, it should have the right class name.

Answer (score 0):

declare your receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
 <receiver android:name=".Receiver" 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

because you have BroadcastReceiver class as `Receiver.class` but declaring it in AndroidManifest.xml with  `MyReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction("com.androidhive.jsonparsing.UpdateService");
context.startService(myIntent);
```

Try doing this instead in the receiver

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
context.startService(myIntent);
```