# Android service not working after reboot, giving ANR error

Tags: java, android

Went through the documentation on how to [start a service automatically after the device boots](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) and tried all they said but couldn't get my service to work after rebooting the device, though it works perfectly well on first instance.
Below is my main activity (MainActivity.java) which starts the service after a button has been clicked, and triggers the service every 10 seconds using AlarmManager.

```
public void onClickSubmitDate(View view) {
    Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, service, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, 10 * 1000, pendingIntent);

    //Enable receiver when device boots
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Below is my receiver class (BootReceiver.java)

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(null, 0, service, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                10 * 1000, 10 * 1000,
                pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

}

My service contains a thread which checks for multiple scenarios and builds a notification for each scenario. Here's a sample below:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    boolean diff = true;
                    if (diff) {
                        // Build the notification
                        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                        notification.setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_ticker));
                        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        notification.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title));
                        notification.setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_1_text));
                        notification.setSound(alarmSound);

                        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                        // Builds a notification and issues it
                        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int rand = r.nextInt(1000);
                        nm.notify(rand, notification.build());
                    }
catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
        };

        Thread stephThread = new Thread(r);
        stephThread.start();

        return START_STICKY;

    }
```

And finally below is my AndroidManifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.motherslove.stephnoutsa.myapplication18calendartest"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyDate"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_date"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: hard to tell... what about the logcat? something there?

Comment: sorry, it tells me the application may be doing too much work then displays "getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4014f40" in red

Comment: You're setting a repeating alarm to run about every 10 seconds, and each time it's building and issuing a Notification. This probably isn't playing nice during boot. Try setting a single, non-repeating alarm to test. Also, if you want to do something every 10 seconds, you really don't want to use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: I changed the alarm repeat time and the time after which the alarm is to start from 10 seconds to 3 minutes, but I'm still getting the error message after reboot...Note that the time used is just for testing purposes

Comment: Are you initializing `context` in the Service's `onCreate()`? What's the `Uri` for the alarm sound?

Comment: Yes i initialize the context using "Context context = this;" and the uri for the alarm sound is "Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);"

Comment: If that's the exact line you have in `onCreate()`, and you've declared a field `Context context;` as well, then those are two different variables named `context`, and the field is not initialized.

Comment: Oh sorry I declared those directly in the class and not in any function...not in the onCreate()

Comment: Well, try initializing those in `onCreate()` instead, but leave the declarations where they're at. Also, you might try temporarily removing the alarm sound altogether. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Oh, wait. You're passing `null` as the first argument in the `PendingIntent.getService()` call in your Receiver. You should be passing `context`.

Comment: Tried all the above but nothing still

Comment: I restarted my Android Studio and now it works. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14334482/2826147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from @MikeM I could fix the problem.
Instead of

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(null, 0, service, 0);
```

I had to pass in the context as the first argument, in the receiver, as shown below

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, service, 0);
```